# Mapping select-all, copy, paste in vim

Tags: vim

I have the following map in my `vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <C-a> ggVG
nnoremap <C-c> "*yy (might be because I'm in visual mode here?)
nnoremap <C-v> "*p
```

The select-all (ctrl-a) and the paste (ctrl-p) works, but the (ctrl-c) does not work with that shortcut, though it works if I manually type in the command after doing ctrl-c.

What needs to be fixed here?

Comment: Why `ctrl-p`? The standard is `ctrl-v` AFAIR

Comment: @phd yes that was a mistake, thanks for catching that.

Comment: The `Ctrl-c` is probably catched by your shell and vim never sees it.

Comment: @rkta yes I think that's the case. How do I get around that? Do I just need to make different shortcuts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first issue I would like to address is that your mapping for copying the text, `nnoremap <C-c> "*yy`, will only work in normal mode. When you select text in Vim, you enter visual mode, and the first `n` of `nnoremap` makes the mapping work in normal mode only.

You can make your mapping work by using `noremap` (all modes), `vnoremap` (visual and select mode), or `xnoremap` (visual mode only), like this:

```
vnoremap <C-c> "*y
```

You can find more information about mappings in the [documentation](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#mapmode-n).

Another thing to note is that the default function of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> is to cancel/interrupt the current command. For example, if you enter insert mode and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>, you will exit insert mode and go back to normal mode. With your original mappings, it will cancel the selection (exits visual mode) without copying anything.

Comment: thanks for this answer. I can do `"+y` and it works when I've pressed my `ctrl-a`, but when I do the key map `vnoremap <c-c> "+y  ` it just beeps (the warning bell) and does nothing. Any idea why that happens? I'm on linux. `ctrl-v` does the same as well -- it doesn't work when I try it on linux.

Comment: Would you please try the following mapping, just to confirm whether the issue is with the keys you press or the clipboard register: `vnoremap <C-c> y`

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in Neovim but I believe it should also work in Vim as well. To yank all the content I have the following mapping in my configuration:

```
nnoremap <leader>ya ggVGy<C-O>
```

Details:

1. `gg`: go to the first line
2. `V`: select the first line
3. `G`: go to the last line
4. `y`: yank selection
5. `<C-O>`: go to the previous cursor position